# Qual a diferença entre Cache::add(), Cache::put(), Cache::set?

Tags: laravel, cache, redis

Estou com essa dúvida de funcionamento desses métodos estáticos. A documentação do Predis é escassa. Não consegui ainda entender a diferença.

Answer (score -3):

O método add só adicionará o item ao cache se ele ainda não existir no armazenamento em cache. O método put você pode remover ou recuperar itens. O método get você pode recuperar itens.
Conforme visto na documentação. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache